# Customize node in netchart

Tags: zoomcharts

I am testing netchart from zoomchart and I have question.

Is possible to customize node?
For example, can I use HTML and style it with CSS or I need use only `Node style attributes`?

I want to display node with image, text, button and hover it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZoomCharts does not support HTML/CSS for chart element styling (only popups such as tooltip and menu). You have to use the styling options provided by the chart.